# Change side bar bootstrap text color from text-light to text-dark on click using jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

Help with adding jQuery that will remove text-light when the side menu is open or when the navbar-toggler button is clicked.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  if (window.jQuery) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".sidebarNavigation .navbar-collapse").hide().clone().appendTo("body").removeAttr("class").addClass("sideMenu").show();
      $("body").append("<div class='overlay'></div>");
      $(".navbar-toggle, .navbar-toggler").on("click", function() {
        $(".sideMenu").addClass($(".sidebarNavigation").attr("data-sidebarClass"));
        $(".sideMenu, .overlay").toggleClass("open");
        $(".overlay").on("click", function() {
          $(this).removeClass("open");
          $(".sideMenu").removeClass("open")
        })
      });
      $("body").on("click", ".sideMenu.open .nav-item", function() {
        if (!$(this).hasClass("dropdown")) {
          $(".sideMenu, .overlay").toggleClass("open")
        }
      });
      $(window).resize(function() {
        if ($(".navbar-toggler").is(":hidden")) {
          $(".sideMenu, .overlay").hide()
        } else {
          $(".sideMenu, .overlay").show()
        }
      })
    })
  } else {
    console.log("sidebarNavigation Requires jQuery")
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-body navbar-dark sidebarNavigation" data-sidebarClass="navbar-dark bg-light ">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="Media/David-Sanders-Logo-Transparent-White-Writing.png" width="210wh" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive logo"></a>
  <!-- Toggler/collapsibe Button -->
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <!-- Navbar links -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center sidenav">

    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="text-danger btn">Home</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="text-light btn">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="text-light btn">About</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="text-light btn">Services</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="text-light btn">Skills</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="text-light btn">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</nav>
```

It would be helpful if this could be implemented into the current jQuery code.

Answer (score 0):

I first took away the text-light class from all list items.

```
<li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="btn">Contact</a></li>
```

Then I was able to achieve the desired result by accessing the nav in css and overriding the bootstrap.

```
nav .navbar-nav li a{
  color: white;
}
```

The problem is solved but not in jQuery which is what I wanted, however, either way achieves the same outcome.